# Is there a way to add custom prefix per user in my discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make a custom prefix command for every user,so when someone does !setprefix it should set prefix for that person and other person cannot use that prefix.Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

As varian you can use database for this, or json file for storage data.
Formats like:

```
{
  "memberID": {
    "prefix": "#"
  },
    "memberID2": {
    "prefix": "@"
  },
    "memberID3": {
    "prefix": "!"
  }
}
```

So on message you need check if this json has message.author.id, and if has use `userPrefix`, if not use `defaultPrefix`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using something such as [Enmap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enmap) with persistent storage. Enmap is a key-pair extension on to javascript's build in `Map()` class. With this you could easily set/get users prefixes.

Answer (score -1):

No there isn't as the bot initialises with a set value for the prefix which cant be changed during run time. This means that you could change the value of a variable called `prefix` but it would not affect the bot until you restarted it and it would have the same value for everyone no matter who set it to what.

Comment: This is actually incorrect. The way people handle prefix's are different based on how you write your code. But the prefix isn't necessarily hard coded. While you do need to provide a "default" prefix, you can write code that checks if the user has set a custom prefix (or even just read a JSON file of users and prefixes).